# Firebase storage delete uidd image

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to delete an uuid image from Firebase Storage. When I add an uuid image, I can delete it from tableview but not from Firebase Storage. If I add an image without uuid, I can delete it with image name without any problem. My problem is how to get uuid image name as a reference.

Here's my code for upload image(in AddViewController) in Firebase Storage:

```
@IBAction func saveButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    // STORAGE

    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let storageReference = storage.reference()

    let mediaFolder = storageReference.child("media")

    let userUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email!

    if let data = childImageView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) {

        let uuid = UUID().uuidString

        let imageReference = mediaFolder.child("\(userUid!)/\(uuid).jpg")

        imageReference.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.makeAlert(titleInput: "Error!", messageInput: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
            } else {

                imageReference.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        let imageUrl = url?.absoluteString
```

Here's my code for delete image (in mainViewController) in Firebase Storage:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        // STORAGE

        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageReference = storage.reference()

        let userUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email!
        let uuid = UUID().uuidString

        let mediaFolder = storageReference.child("media").child("\(userUid!)/\(uuid).jpg")

        mediaFolder.delete { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Image Error")
            } else {
                print("Image Deleted")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUID is unique and creating new UUID (as you do when you call `UUID()`) is generating a new one (with misery chance of collision). You should hold object identifier (its UUID) inside your cell model